# How do you extend/inherit an elixir module?

Tags: elixir

Let's say an elixir library defines:

```
defmodule Decoder do

  def decode(%{"BOOL" => true}),    do: true
  def decode(%{"BOOL" => false}),   do: false
  def decode(%{"BOOL" => "true"}),  do: true
  def decode(%{"BOOL" => "false"}), do: false
  def decode(%{"B" => value}),      do: value
  def decode(%{"S" => value}),      do: value
  def decode(%{"M" => value}),      do: value |> decode
  def decode(item = %{}) do
    item |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn({k, v}, map) ->
      Map.put(map, k, decode(v))
    end)
  end
end
```

I want to define a module `MyDecoder` which just adds one more `def decode` to the above module.  In an oo language, this would be done by inheritance/mixin/extends of some sort.

How do I do this in elixir?

Comment: For instance, I need to add `def decode(%{"NULL" => true}), do: nil` to `ExAws.Dynamo.Decoder` at https://github.com/CargoSense/ex_aws/blob/c8d62612a427ef5cf6cfd74b772dcf82e90ab567/lib/ex_aws/dynamo/decoder.ex

Comment: Is this a bug in the implementation? If so, how about making a PR and using your own fork until the fix is released?

Comment: Doing that.  Was wondering what the general solution in elixir looks like.  As far as I can tell, there is no clean way to extend a module with just one function without rewriting the original library.

Comment: elixir should consider adding a `includes`/`extends`.

Comment: Well this is only a problem in the very specific case of a broken implementation of a recursive function, where you do not control the entire source code. Most othe problems that OO solves with inheritance can actually be solved quite elegantly in Elixir. That said, even OO will not allow you to add a clause like you are trying to do here or am I mistaken?

Comment: As I said below @anshul, there are ways to extend the behavior without modifying the original source code but in this particular case (and we're always talking about details when we're talking about code, right?) it's a lot of effort for not a lot of gain. Part of engineering is weighing cost against benefit. Extending this code via a protocol would be a lot of cost for little benefit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, you can. Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/orenbenkiki/5174435) which uses some rather "obscure" methods for listing a module's public functions and then generating delegates out of them. It's pretty cool.

Here is where it's all about:

```elixir
defmodule Extension do
  defmacro extends(module) do
    module = Macro.expand(module, __CALLER__)
    functions = module.__info__(:functions)
    signatures = Enum.map functions, fn { name, arity } ->
      args = if arity == 0 do
               []
             else
               Enum.map 1 .. arity, fn(i) ->
                 { binary_to_atom(<< ?x, ?A + i - 1 >>), [], nil }
               end
             end
      { name, [], args }
    end
    quote do
      defdelegate unquote(signatures), to: unquote(module)
      defoverridable unquote(functions)
    end
  end
end
```

You can use it like so:

```elixir
defmodule MyModule do
   require Extension
   Extension.extends ParentModule
   # ...
end
```

Unfortunately, it throws a warning on the most recent Elixir builds, but I'm sure that can be solved. Other than that, it works like a charm!

Edited so as not to throw a warning:

```elixir
defmodule Extension do
  defmacro extends(module) do
    module = Macro.expand(module, __CALLER__)
    functions = module.__info__(:functions)
    signatures = Enum.map functions, fn { name, arity } ->
      args = if arity == 0 do
               []
             else
               Enum.map 1 .. arity, fn(i) ->
                 { String.to_atom(<< ?x, ?A + i - 1 >>), [], nil }
               end
             end
      { name, [], args }
    end

    zipped = List.zip([signatures, functions])
    for sig_func <- zipped do
      quote do
        defdelegate unquote(elem(sig_func, 0)), to: unquote(module)
        defoverridable unquote([elem(sig_func, 1)])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 21):

There is a mechanism to extend the behavior of a module.  It's called a protocol.  You can find more information [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html).  You can think of an Elixir protocol as being analogous to an interface in OO.

But, in this particular case, it's like swatting a fly with a sledgehammer. I mean you could probably rewrite the code to use a protocol but if you want to simply extend the parser then fork the code and make your modification.  Oh and don't forget to send a PR back to the original developer because he might like to have your fix as well.

Sometimes the simplest answer is the best one.  Even if this were OO code, if some developer inherited the class or something like that I'd flag that in the code review.  Why?  Because inheritance leads to pathological [code coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)).

In general in FP (and note that I'm making a big generalization here) the way we usually extend behavior is via higher-order functions.  That is, if we want different behavior we don't use polymorphism; we simply directly pass the behavior we want to a higher-order function.  What do I mean when I say "pass the behavior"?.  Consider I've got some validation code for example:

```
defmodule V do
  def is_odd?(v) do
    rem(v,2) != 0
  end
end

defmodule T do
   def is_valid_value?(v, f) do
     if f(v), do: true, else: false
   end
end
```

And somewhere else I'll have `T.is_valid_value?(myvalue, V.is_odd?)`.  And suddenly my customer realizes that rather than checking if the value is odd they need to check if it's greater than 100.  So I would do something along these lines:

```
defmodule V do
  def greater_than_100?(v) do
    v > 100
  end
end
```

And then I would change my call to this: `T.is_valid_value?(myvalue, V.greater_than_100?)`

*NB: I am deliberately keeping the code pretty simple to make a point. This may not be valid syntax. I haven't checked and I can't right now.*

That's it. That's all. Intelligent developers can disagree but to me that's a lot more straightforward and easier to follow than inheriting behavior and overriding it.

Comment: I think the original question referred to an external library, which he did not want to touch.

Comment: If he was referring to an external library, it wasn't clear from his question.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps `defdelegate` would do the trick:

```
defmodule MyDecoder do
  def decode(%{"X" => value}), do: value

  defdelegate decode(map), to: Decoder
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't control the original module I am not sure whether there is a straightforward solution to this. Maybe you can try to pre-process the data recursively, then feed the result to the original implementation.

If you can control the original module however, one way to do this is by extracting the common clauses into a macro, then using this in your actual decoder modules:

```
defmodule Decoder.Common do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      def decode(%{"BOOL" => true}),    do: true
      def decode(%{"BOOL" => false}),   do: false
      def decode(%{"BOOL" => "true"}),  do: true
      def decode(%{"BOOL" => "false"}), do: false
      def decode(%{"B" => value}),      do: value
      def decode(%{"S" => value}),      do: value
      def decode(%{"M" => value}),      do: value |> decode
      def decode(item = %{}) do
        item |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn({k, v}, map) ->
          Map.put(map, k, decode(v))
        end)
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Decoder do
  use Decoder.Common
end

defmodule MyDecoder do
  def decode(%{"FOO" => value}), do: "BAR"

  use Decoder.Common
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work because Decoder.decode(x) will not be able to call MyDecoder.decode as it works it's way through the recursion/delegation.