# How to modify existing module behaviour in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is it possible to add a new functionality to the module which doesn't have `__using__/1` function?

For example, I would like to add `get_meta_by_key` function to Phoenix.Tracker. If I go with

```
defmodule MyApp.MyTracker do
  use Phoenix.Tracker

  def get_meta_by_key(..., topic, key)
    ...
  end

  handle_call(:get_meta_by_key, ..., state)
    ...
  end
end
```

then I get `** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function Phoenix.Tracker.__using__/1`

I would like to have distributed in-memory key-value store to keep some temporary values but can't figure out how to do it without reinventing the wheel and without using `Phoenix.Tracker.list` function and then dealing with the full list on the caller side.

I'm pretty new in Elixir/Phoenix, so please excuse me if my question is stupid.

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at this Q & A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302208/how-do-you-extend-inherit-an-elixir-module

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, thanks a lot for the point! But I can't find the normal way to implement a very little addition (couple lines of code, actually) without forking of the existed module (and then getting a big headache on supporting and upgrading it). It's not so easy to switch to a functional way after years of OOP, but at the moment I can't even imagine how to realize what I need in a simple and effective way.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Of course, I can make a "higher level" function which will work with the full list returned from Tracker but I believe it isn't an effective way: if I understand correctly, this will copy the whole list on every call.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that it will copy the entire list on every call.  In fact I'd assume quite the opposite.  I'd assume that a pointer to the list will get passed silently every time.  But that's me.  If you're asking for the "functional" way to extend behavior, a higher-order function is the conventional way to do so.

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't alter code based on assumptions.  I'd try to get empirical data first and then if I had empirical evidence, then I'd alter my code to deal with whichever problem presented itself. Guessing on performance is premature optimization.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, [Phoenix.Tracker.list](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_pubsub/blob/master/lib/phoenix_pubsub/tracker.ex#L188) is a remote call. May be I'm wrong but I can't imagine how could it be done with a pointer (doesn't matter if it parameter or return value). What if the server is on another node?

By the way, thank you for the opinion, I went with a higher-order function at the moment. But still would like to have this functionality inside of the tracker worker - at least until I realize that it has no performance penalty.

Comment: Good point @heathen but I still wouldn't worry about the performance of the underlying implementation (either way) until I had empirical evidence that it's actually a problem. Don't assume copying the list is going to be a performance issue until someone says "Hey this needs to work faster"

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own using macros with [using](https://devdocs.io/elixir/ex_unit/exunit.casetemplate#using/2). This is metaprogramming related and I highly recommend looking at Metaprogramming Elixir book for this. You will also need to use `quote` and `unquote` for it.

You may also refer to [this](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/domain-specific-languages.html#the-test-macro)

Comment: Sasha, thanks a lot for your answer! 

Excuse me if I wasn't clear enough. Phoenix.Tracker - it's already existed module. I don't want to hack it to keep normal upgrade way, otherwise I would just copy it and hack. I would like to extend this module but don't know how to do it.

Or do I misunderstand your idea? Please explain it then.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't recall any way to extend it without it having the using macro. What I'm thinking may work is to have another module (let's call it TrackerExtender), where you import the functions from Phoenix.Tracker inside a using macro in TrackerExtender. This way when your MyTracker module calls the use TrackerExtender he will receive the function from Phoenix.Tracker and the newly defined ones in TrackerExtender. 

But I'm not completely sure if this works or if it fits your needs.

Comment: Sasha, thank you for your time! I wasn't able to get your solution to work, but can't be sure that it isn't because of my poor elixir skills.