# How to initialize list using macros and then generate same set of functions in 2 different modules?

Tags: metaprogramming, elixir

Is it possible to initialize list using macros and then with another macro generate 2 sets of functions in 2 different modules based on that list?

Pseudo code example:

```
defmodule ABC do
  defmacro rules() do
    quote do
      defrule("a")
      |> defrule("b")
      |> defrule("c")
    end
  end
end

defmodule BasicTokenizer do
  use TokenizerBuilder
  require ABC

  ABC.rules()
  |> deftokenizer()
end


defmodule ExtendedTokenizer do
  use TokenizerBuilder
  require ABC

  ABC.rules()
  |> defrule("d")
  |> deftokenizer() 
end

import ExUnit.Assertions, only: [assert: 1, assert: 2]

assert BasicTokenizer.tokenize("a") == "a"
assert BasicTokenizer.tokenize("b") == "b"
assert BasicTokenizer.tokenize("c") == "c"
assert ExtendedTokenizer.tokenize("a") == "a"
assert ExtendedTokenizer.tokenize("b") == "b"
assert ExtendedTokenizer.tokenize("c") == "c"
assert ExtendedTokenizer.tokenize("d") == "d"
```

I tried following approach but I'm stuck in `deftokenizer`:

```
defmodule TokenizerBuilder do

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      require unquote(__MODULE__)
      import unquote(__MODULE__)
    end
  end

  defmacro defrule(str) do
    quote do
      [unquote(str)]
    end
  end

  defmacro defrule(rules, str) do
    quote do
      Enum.concat(unquote(rules), [unquote(str)])
    end
  end

  defmacro deftokenizer(rules) do
    # rules is AST, how to get builded list value outside quote?
    Enum.each(rules, fn(str) ->
      quote do
        def tokenize(unquote(str)) do
          unquote(str)
        end
      end
    end)
  end
end
```

Comment: Please show us what is the desired outcome.

Comment: I have expanded example with `assert` to show outcome.

Comment: is there a reason you want/need to delay code generation this way? Generating the code in the `build` steps directly would be much easier, of course (and please let's not get hung up on OO patterns like `Builder` here ;-)). Short of that, you can probably define a recursive function with arguments pattern matching the pseudo-AST (shooting from the hip - `generate_one({_name, _info, [rest, my_name]})` which recurses into `rest` to traverse this structure.

Comment: @cdegroot Yes. As I've written in the last post statement - later I want to share created list and generate code in different modules. Pattern matching AST by myself doesn't seem elegant / the right way.

Comment: I think this could be done without resorting to macros.  Maybe you think you need macros because you think you need to somehow vary behavior based on input.  Functional languages allow you to pass around functions the way that imperative languages allow you to pass data--so you may not need to use macros at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking for but consider this code:

```
iex(1)> f = &String.upcase/1
&String.upcase/1
iex(2)> g = &String.trim/1
&String.trim/1
iex(3)> h = &String.reverse/1
&String.reverse/1
iex(4)> fs = [f,g,h]
[&String.upcase/1, &String.trim/1, &String.reverse/1]
iex(5)> r = for f <- fs, do: f.("hello")
["HELLO", "hello", "olleh"]
```

I mean if you're trying to build a list of functions to apply to a value, then this may work.  I think there are ways to build a list of functions to apply to a value without having to resort to macros to do so.  But your use case is far from clear to me.

Comment: Pretty much I'm asking to use macros to initialize list and then pipe it to final macro that does code generation. The example is generic, but you can imagine I want to achieve some kind of module extension. The list is set of rules for tokenizer. There are two tokenizers - one basic, second adding additional rules, so I want to share common rules in some data structure and then generate the same set of functions in both modules. I guess it's kind of similar problem that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302208/how-do-you-extend-inherit-an-elixir-module

Comment: Ok, so I'm still not following you then @Marina.  Your tokenizers are functions aren't they?  So you could structure the behavior of your tokenizers as a list of functions applied to the data in sequence couldn't you?  I guess what I'm getting at is that I think there are ways to do what you want without resorting to macros.

Comment: Ok, I follow you now. I like simpler code, so I could do what you suggest if it would work with pattern matching / guards. Can you modify your example in way only one function (f or g or h) gets executed based on input (patten matching)?