# How can I "inject" new functions into an existing module in the Elixir language itself?

Tags: elixir

Elixir the language itself has the following module with some methods such as:

```
defmodule Calendar.ISO do
  @spec leap_year?(year) :: boolean()
  @impl true
  def leap_year?(year) when is_integer(year) and year >= 0 do
    rem(year, 4) === 0 and (rem(year, 100) > 0 or rem(year, 400) === 0)
  end
end
```

Let's say I'm writing my own module in my own toy Elixir/Phoenix application and I decide I wanted to add another method in Calendar.ISO called "frog_day" which returns the string "frog".  Obviously, I don't want to make a PR for "frog_day" into the Elixir language repository.

How would I go about injecting this in the Calendar.ISO module for use in my toy app? Or is this even possible?

Note: I realize this may come across as "monkey-patching" but I do have a specific use case for it.

Comment: You'll need to create a new module (i.e. MyCalendar) that extends Calendar.ISO. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302208/how-do-you-extend-inherit-an-elixir-module) which I think is close what you're looking for.

Comment: Monkey patching is explicitly disallowed in Elixir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don’t.

Hacks with `expand` as shown in the answer linked by @matov <s>should</s> must be avoided (especially taken into account, that the linked answer does not do what you want.) Polymorphism in Elixir is being done with [`Protocols`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html) and/or [`Behaviours`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html#behaviours). In your case you don’t need the polymorphism either, just implement your own helper like:

```
defmodule Extensions.Calendar.ISO do
  def frog_day?(day), do: "frog"
end
```

and you are all set. There is *no one single advantage* to even try to put the method inside a foreign module (and you can’t in the first place since the module is already compiled at the moment.)