# Wrap elixir module

Tags: elixir

If you have a module, for instance

```
defmodule Foo do
    # lots of "unknown" functions
end
```

How can I create a wrapper-module for that `Foo`, like:

```
defmodule Bar do
    # wrap all functions in Foo
end
```

But in `Bar` I want to expose all functions in `Foo`, but additionally I want to add some code in each function, specifically I want to `try/catch` a specific error that can show up in any `Foo.Error` exception... I'd like to do this without adding a function for each function in `Foo`, since that will get repetetive.

Can I do this with macros?

Comment: there are several ways to do this and all involve macros. Either implement `defmacro __using__()` in Foo and then add `use Foo` in `Bar`, or create inline code in Bar module that should read `Foo.__info__(:functions)` and "redefine" all in Bar. Question is do you really need this?  it smells like bad decision and documenting inherited functions may be a tricky.

Comment: on the other hand, there are many examples of similar thing when developers conditionally speaking "inherit" genserver for instance. This is done with `use` where macro __using__(..) is executed during compile time, in some cases there is @beforecomple hook which allows "used" module to run its function just before compilation.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIU you want to perform some kind of object-oriented programming by replicating the logic of inheritance between classes. But this is not the philosophy of any functional programming language like Elixir as you probably already know.

However, If this is really what you want to do, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302208/how-do-you-extend-inherit-an-elixir-module) that uses metaprogramming and aim at doing something similar to what you are looking for. It looks complicated though.

Edit : After we had some further talk I understand your problem better. If you want to define function without too much repetition then metaprogramming is the way to go ! Here is a simple example on how to define several functions in a module thanks to metaprogramming :

```
defmodule MyModule do
  Enum.each ~w(method1 method2), fn(method_name) ->
    def unquote(:"#{method_name}")(), do: unquote(method_name)
  end
end
```

> I'd like to do this without adding a function for each function in Foo, since that will get repetetive.

I think that's what I would do, but are you sure it would be that repetitive ?

Also you can also use the [Exceptional lib](https://github.com/expede/exceptional) that will help you write less error-handling functions :)

Comment: Rather than being something motivated by a misplaced desire to replicate OOP in Elixir, I interpreted OP's question as closer to wanting to map a higher-order function (one which sends functions to functions with better error-handling) over a module, which seems like a fairly functional thing to do.

Comment: @JohnColeman I agree ! maybe trying to do metaprogramming to replicate the behaviour of Phoenix's action_fallback (https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#action_fallback/1) would help, but this looks very complicated to me, whereas writing a few function that you just call in a line in each function with a pipe operator doesn't sound that repetitive.

Comment: I know the philosophy isn't to use try/catch in that way, but I still want to catch a certain error that show up in *any* of the functions within a 3rd party module I'm wrapping

Comment: @UjCorb the way I solved it it was very repetetive, because in module `Bar` I had every function from `Foo` defined, but I was imagining there was a way to solve it using only *one* function + some macro magic :)

Comment: @gunnar2k I am not sure what is the repetitive part : is it the try/catch logic ? If so I guess you can write a helper function that has this try/catch logic and that takes a function as argument, then call it with the pipe operator in your functions, right ? :)

Comment: The repetetive part is actually defining each function within the module and copying each function argument, and also the try/catch part within each module. I see your point with the helper function for try/catch tho, that would minimize it slightly. But what about the function definitions & arguments?

Comment: OK i see ! indeed, metaprogramming would be the way to go then; is the code you want to add in each function of the `Foo` module the same all the time ? or actually different from each function ?

Comment: @UjCorb Awesome. It's different for each function, and could be different arguments for each function as well, but they could all potentially throw the same error

Comment: Ok :) I added a simple metaprogramming example to define functions in a loop. Maybe you can start from there. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

With magic of metaprogramming everything is possible (however not always this makes sense):

```
defmodule Bar do
  Code.ensure_compiled(Foo)

  for {func, arity} <- Foo.__info__(:functions) do
    args = Macro.generate_arguments(arity, __MODULE__)

    def unquote(func)(unquote_splicing(args)) do
      Foo.unquote(func)(unquote_splicing(args))
    rescue
      Foo.Error -> handle_error()
    end
  end
end
```

However this will not work for macros.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use of defmacro, but definitely look into defedelegate as well. It lets you add(delegate) named references to functions in other/external modules.